# Why do I get the "Class 'Drupal\Core\Database' not found" error?

Tags: 8, database

I am using the following code.

```
$conn = Database::getConnection();
$conn->insert('testimonial')->fields(array('name' => $form_state->getValue('name')))->execute();
```

I get the following error:

> Class 'Drupal\Core\Database' not found

I am using `use Drupal\Core\Database;`. What is wrong in my code?

Update: i find using namespaces a problem, like now i want to get row count, if insert was successfull or not. i tried with

```
$result->allowRowCount = TRUE;
if ($result->rowCount() == 0) { }
```

and for rowcount i added the name space use Drupal\Core\Database;
i get

> Cannot use Drupal\Core\Database as Database because the name is already in use in

and if i remove this . i get

> Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection::rowCount()

How to use namespaces exactly. like i am assuming if i do

> use Drupal\Core\Database

then all the classes in that namespace and all the children namespace should get inehrited. Is this right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Drupal\Core\Database` is the namespace of the class, which is not what the `use` statement requires. It needs the full-qualified class name, which, for that class, is `Drupal\Core\Database\Database`.

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
```

That is what Drupal core uses, for example in the [DbLog.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21dblog%21src%21Logger%21DbLog.php/8.2.x) file.

```
namespace Drupal\dblog\Logger;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
use Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseException;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\DependencySerializationTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Logger\LogMessageParserInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Logger\RfcLoggerTrait;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
```